# Windows batch script goto error

Tags: batch-file

i have been trying to write a batch script in windows 7 sp1. After i start my batch script i try to type an option into the input and then i get "goto unexpected at this time" then the command prompt closes. Please help i need this for a personal project.

```
@echo off
:start
echo Is this the first time you ran this program on this computer 
set input=
set /p intput= "y/n"
if%input%==yes goto Yes
if%input%==no goto No

:No
pause
echo Okay skipping the installation process
cd Minecraft_Server
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server*.jar
goto serverrestart

:serverrestart
echo Would you like to restart the server?
set input=
set /p intput= y or n
if%input%==y 
pause
goto restart
if%input%==n 
pause
goto norestart

:restart
echo To restart the server press any key.
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server*.jar
goto serverrestart

:norestart
exit

:Yes 
pause
echo I will now install the Minecraft Serevr files, please make sure you 
echo have me in the "Parent Directory" of the Minecraft_Server folder
echo --If you don't know what a parent directory is GOOGLE it!--
pause
mkdir Minecraft_Server
move files.exe Minecraft_Server
cd Minecraft_Server
start files.exe
timeout /t 3
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server*.jar
goto :serverrestart
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled input in the set /p line and you should use quotes.  I used /i to make the compare case insensitive and shortened to one key required.  Do as you wish with that.  Try this:

```
@echo off
:start
echo Is this the first time you ran this program on this computer 
set "input="
set /p input= "y/n"
if /i "%input%"=="y" goto :Yes
if /i "%input%"=="n" goto :No
echo.Enter a valid choice
pause
goto :start
```